# Core data fetch using specific object rather than object attribute

Tags: core-data, fetch

I have been searching the forum and found some code on another users question which is 99% of what I am after. Code fragment below...

```
Bookshop *bookshop = (Bookshop *) nsManagedObjectFromOwner;

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Books" 
                      inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
          @"ANY bookshop.Name == '%@'", 
          bookshop.Name];
[fetchRequest setPredicate: predicate];
```

In this fetch, the predicate is searching for all books that belong to a bookshop of a particular name. In my app, however, my equivalent of bookshop is clients, and it is possible that clients could have the same name. What is the best way to set the predicate given I havent declared any unique indentifiers in the client entity myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh...I have figured this one out. For those who have the same question...

...If you already have the 'bookshop' object, you can simply use the following notation to refer to its 'books'...

```
bookshop.books
```

So this could be used as follows...

```
NSSet *books = bookshop.books;
NSArray *booksArray = [[NSArray alloc] init]]
booksArray = [books allObjects];
```

You then has a NSArray with all your books objects you can use.

Hey presto!!